# PC partially freezes, won't always boot or shutdown

Tags: windows-10, boot, memory, ssd, freeze

Don't want to waste your time, so let's dive into the symptoms:

• Windows 10 PC displayed black screen after installing AMD drivers. Could recover by unistalling drivers in safe mode.

• After clean install of windows, pc worked fine for a few hours, then it slowly freezed. By slowly I mean, I could move some windows, could close some, but after a while only cursor was moving. Freezes looked related to vga (AMD 7970), cause the often happend when I watched a video, but that could be totaly random.

• I found out that my cpu (i5 3570k @ 4.4GHz) temps where insanely high (100+°C), so I used the stock clock speed. That droped the temps to a maximum of 60°C, but PC kept freezing.

• Tried to run memtest overnigh, but in the morning all I found was a cursor (movable) in a black screen, so no results there.

• I completly unistalled my vga and I pluged my screen directly on the motherboard, using the HD graphics. I had to boot twice to boot into windows and everything seemed fine, thinking that the vga was the problem. PC started freezing again but not so often and it would never freeze to a point where only the cursor moves. I even managed to have a file copied over a thumb drive while PC seemed like it was almost completly frozen again (every open window was unresponsive but could be moved around).

• I found out that one of my drives (data storing SSD), was on 100% utilization, even when nothing in task manager was using it.

• Windows gives no error on disks, but last time I tried to check my data SSD, test froze immediately, and the rest of my PC followed up...

• Now, I can't boot into Windows. It either display's spinning dots on a black screen or a windows logo screen, or "Diagnosing your PC", and the dots freeze.

• Windows finally loaded the repair menu (reset your pc, safe mode, etc), but Windows won't load even in safe mode.

So, could someone please point my towards a possible solution to my problem or at least find for sure what is causing it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Capacitor blown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out the answer myself!

The problem was that one of my drives was peaking in usage, causing the system to freeze, even though that wasn't the boot drive. I disabled both prefetch and superfetch in Windows 10 (that's how you do it: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-superfetch-prefetch-ssd) and now I only have some minor hang-ups for a few seconds, a little after I log into Windows, still caused by high drive usage. That still indicates a problem, but at least now the PC is totally usable.